# Change $config variable name in HTML Purifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I'm using HTML Purifier and saw a naming conflict with my existing code. The variable `$config` (an array) is already in use in my code for my config.ini file but based on the [HTML Purifier docs](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs), it's also using $config (as object) for customization. Is there a way to **rename the $config used by HTML Purifier** to something like `$htmlpur_config`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your configuration object just name it differently

```
<?php
    require_once '/path/to/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

    $htmlpur_config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $htmlpur_config->set('Core.Encoding', 'ISO-8859-1'); // replace with your encoding
    $htmlpur_config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional'); // replace with your doctype
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($htmlpur_config);

    $clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
?>
```

The key is creating the `$config` object and passing it into the constructor for the `HTMLPurifier`

Comment: Thanks for adding sample code @danielrsmith. I can honestly say that my question is idiotic to say at the very least. Haha

Comment: Don't be sorry, their documentation was a bit confusing if you don't read the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a different variable:

```
// Instead of
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

// Use
$htmlpurifier_config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$htmlpurifier_config->set('some.setting', 'somevalue');
```